# Problem with MySQL and Rails Server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Final edit: I played with a few different files got some more errors and then reinstalled rvm and everything else from the start, found a few fixes and edited them and finally everything works. thank you everyone for your help

Edit: I have noticed that it says Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)

But I have mysql 5.5.11, how do I fix that?

I literally have searched for the past 3 hours, but found nothing that **worked**

Same error occurs when I either try to launch the server or generate a model

I have bundler and mysql2 gems.

builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.12)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.17)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql2 (0.2.7)

I get the following output:

```
    hrs772:demo kishinmanglani$ rails s
/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/rails_projects/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Taking a wild stab here..have you tried using another mysql gem? The ones I know of are `mysql`, '`mysql2`, and `mysql-ruby`.

Comment: I have not, but I would rather have the issue resolved with the  mysql2 gem instead of just switch to the mysql or mysql-ruby gems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get load errors you should make sure you have all of the dependencies installed and in place.

1. Make sure you have `gem mysql2` in your Gemfile.
2. Install bundler if you don't already have it with `gem install bundler`.
3. Run `bundle` (same as `bundle install`).

Then try running the server again.

Answer (score 0):

mysql2 with rails 3.0.3 is give some error so try to update rails version with 3.0.6

it working fine so try

Comment: I am actually using rails 3.0.7

Comment: rails 3.0.7 is not stable now it also give me error with jruby so try with rails 3.0.6 its more stable its working realy good

Comment: now i get the error Could not find rails-3.0.7 in any of the sources after installing 3.0.6 and uninstalling 3.0.7

Comment: change in gemfile gem"rails 3.0.6" and check with rails -v